# Understanding the push function

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am having difficulties understanding the push function for a linked list in C. Take for example I have the following structure

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

and I have created a linked list as such

```
  // creating list
  node_t * head = NULL;
  head = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

  // checking if list is initialised sucessfully
  if (head == NULL) {
      return 1;
  }

  // 1st and 2nd element
  head = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  head->val = 1;    
  head->next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  head->next->val = 2;
  head->next->next = NULL;
```

the push function is given as such

```
void push(node_t ** head, int val) {
    node_t * new_node;
    new_node = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

---

My question is why is `new_node->next` assigned to the dereferenced `head`? I thought `head` is supposed to be a pointer, thus making `*head` the next `node_t` itself. `new_node.next` is a pointer, hence it should be `new_node->next = head` instead?

Secondly, is the last line `*head = new_node` the same as `head = &new_node`? Even more so , is it the same as `**head = &new_node`? The last one would make the most sense to me, since we are passing a pointer of a pointer as an argument of `push`.

Comment: Notice that `head`has two stars in its declaration. This makes it a pointer to a _pointer_.  So `*head` is a pointer, which points to the old head of the list. It's updated to be the new node by the final line of the function.

Comment: This method of addition to a list is know as *forward chaining*. You will end up with elements in reverse order to the order read. (you are adding the new elements at the front of the list and making what was the list available through the `->next` pointer and then setting the list address to the new node)

Comment: OT: your first `malloc` should be deleted. And consequently the `if` statement as well.

Comment: Please post complete verifiable code. In your list creation code how is local variable `head` used afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why is `new_node->next` assigned to the dereferenced `head`?

Because the `head` parameter of function `push` is a pointer to the head pointer.  You must dereference it once to get the (presumed) pointer to the head node of your linked list.  This must of course be matched on the caller's side -- they must pass the address of the list's head pointer.

> I thought `head` is supposed to be a pointer, thus making `*head` the next `node_t` itself.

The code presented muddles this a bit by using the same identifier, "`head`", in different scopes to represent different levels of indirection.  In function `push`, parameter `head` is a `node_t **`.  Yes, that is a pointer, but not to the head node.  Instead, it points to another pointer, which in turn points to the head node.  `*head` there is a `node_t *`, not a `node_t`.

> Secondly, is the last line `*head = new_node` the same as `head = &new_node`? Even more so , is it the same as `**head = &new_node`?

No, those are all different, which follows immediately from the fact that `head`, `*head`, and `**head` all designate different objects.  In function `push()`,

- `head` designates the function parameter, which has type `node_t **` *and is local to the function*.  The assignment `head = &new_node` would be type-correct and overall valid, setting `head` to point to the function's local variable `new_node`, but that would be of little use, since it conveys nothing back to the function's caller, and it serves no particular purpose within the function itself.
- `*head` of course designates the object to which `head` points, as chosen by the function's caller.  It has type `node_t *`.  That pointer object is accessible to the caller and could, for example, be one of the caller's local variables.  The assignment `*head = new_node` modifies that caller-accessible object, and its effect is therefore visible to the caller, which is the purpose of the parameter being a double pointer.
- `**head` designates the object to which `*head` points, a `node_t`.  That object, too, is accessible to the caller, but modifying it would not serve the function's purposes.  The caller would then be left with the same one `node_t` object, just with different contents.  In any case, the expression `&new_node`, a `node_t **`, does not have the correct type for assignment to `**head`.  If one actually meant to assign to it then a type-correct (but semantically inappropriate) option would be `**head = *new_node`.

> The last one would make the most sense to me, since we are passing a pointer of a pointer as an argument of `push`.

The reason for passing a pointer to a pointer is so that the pointed-to *pointer* can be modified by the function.  The result is that afterward, the caller's pointer points to the node allocated by `push`, whereas that node's `next` pointer points to the node to which the caller's pointer initially pointed.  This is exactly what is wanted for adding a node to the list.  The **caller**'s view looks something like this:

*before push()*

```
  X --next--> ... --next--> NULL
  |
  v
Value1        ...
```

*after push(Value2)*

```
  Y --next--> X --next--> ... --next--> NULL
  |           |
  v           v
Value2      Value1        ...
```

***If `push` instead assigned to `**head`***, however, the result would be

```
  X --next--> (depends)
  |
  v
Value2
```

Note that `Value1` is now gone, replaced by `Value2`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `push` function, `head` is a '**pointer**' to a '**pointer to the head node**'.  For the purpose of understanding the code, it may be more helpful to think of `head` as '**the address of**' the '**pointer to the head node**'.

The code in the `push` function is:

1. taking the current '**pointer to the head node**' (by dereferencing `head`) and attaching it to the `next` member of the `new_node`, and
2. making `new_node` the new *list head* by taking the pointer to the `new_node` and writing it back to the '**pointer to the head node**' by dereferencing `head`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers.

Be mindful about what you do with your "list" when it is empty with your pop/push operations. And think what are you going to consider "emptiness" in your internal representation. Is there going to be a head pointing to nothing, or there going to be "fake" node?

Technically speaking, what you making is *queue* and typical test on it is to fill it, then drain up to empty and then try drain again from empty.

PS. A little style remark. You are using 'struct node => node_t'. You could simply substitute 'node_t' with 'struct node' in your code. Just no practical difference. But if you chose it to be pointer to struct, code will read much better (in further developments).